# discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.utility' raised an error: IndentationError: expected an indented block utility.py line 11

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a cog called "Utility" for my discord bot however I am having issues with my ping command.

The rest of my bot including the cog loading systems work fine.

The code for the cog is;

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class Utility(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        author = ctx.message.author

        embed = discord.Embed(
            colour = discord.Colour.green()
        )

        embed.add_field(name='Pong!', value=(f'{round(bot.latency * 1000)}ms'), inline=False)

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Utility(bot))
```

Also if it is needed, the ping command itself does not work in any other part of the bot.

The error is;

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\My Microsoft User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 596, in _load_from_module_spec
    spec.loader.exec_module(lib)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 779, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 916, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 846, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\My Microsoft User\Desktop\Discord Bot Coding\DTOG Bot\cogs\utility.py", line 11
    author = ctx.message.author
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\My Microsoft User\Desktop\Discord Bot Coding\DTOG Bot\bot.py", line 61, in <module>
    bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
  File "C:\Users\My Microsoft User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 653, in load_extension
    self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "C:\Users\My Microsoft User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 599, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.utility' raised an error: IndentationError: expected an indented block (utility.py, line 11)
```

EDIT 10/10/2020

Since people are having issues here is my cog loader;

```py
import discord
import random
import asyncio
import time
import youtube_dl
import functools
import itertools
import math
import sys
import traceback
import pycountry
import os
from functools import partial
from async_timeout import timeout
from discord.ext import commands
from random import choice

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 'dtog!')
bot.remove_command('help')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('The bot is online!')
    ...
    bot.loop.create_task(status_task())

async def status_task():
    while True:
        await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="DTOG code"))
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="dtog!help!"))
        await asyncio.sleep(5)

@bot.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    id = str(ctx.author.id)
    if id == '721029142602056328':
        bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
    else:
        await ctx.send("You can't do this!")

        embed.add_field(name='Pong!', value=(f'{round(self.bot.latency * 1000)}ms'), inline=False)

@bot.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    id = str(ctx.author.id)
    if id == 'MY DISCORD ID':
        bot.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
    else:
        await ctx.send("You can't do this!")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def shutdown(ctx):
    id = str(ctx.author.id)
    if id == 'MY DISCORD ID':
        await ctx.send('Shutting down...')
        await ctx.bot.logout()
    else:
        await ctx.send("You can't do this!")

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')

bot.run('MY TOKEN')
```

Comment: You dont even use the line `author = ctx.message.author` why not just get rid of it

Comment: done but it didnt do anything

Comment: Do you still have the error?

Comment: I believe you must have a title for your embed

Comment: I am still having the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem.

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author

    embed = discord.Embed(
        colour = discord.Colour.dark_blue()
    )

    embed.add_field(name='Pong!', value=(f'{round(bot.latency * 1000)}ms'), inline=False)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```